# Bash script for loop syntax error

Tags: bash, for-loop, cluster-computing, pbs

I have the following syntax error:

```
    line 1: syntax error near unexpected token 'do'
    line 1: for((ARC_LENGTH = 4363325; ARC_LENGTH < 4363345; ARC_LENGTH+=174533)); do
```

I can't spot the error here although I believe it is relatively simple and I am just missing it. The whole file is below. The purpose of this file is to use portable batch software with a bash script so that I can submit multiple jobs to a computing cluster.

```
    for((ARC_LENGTH = 4363325; ARC_LENGTH < 4363345; ARC_LENGTH+=174533)); do
       for((i = 0; i < 64; i++)); do
           qsub -v ARC_LENGTH_ARG=$ARC_LENGTH,NEUTRINO_BOUNDS=$i correlation_study.pbs
           sleep 10
       done
    done
```

This file uses another file called correlation_study.pbs which contains an executable to run the program.

Comment: what is your bash version? are you sure you are using bash to run it?

Comment: You are most likely running your script with something other than `bash`.

Comment: Add `ps $$` above your loop and check the output. If it does not say `bash` you are using something different. Prefix your script with `#! /bin/bash` to use `bash`.

Comment: I am using bash 4.1. Also, I use the chmod +x command to turn this file into an executable.

Comment: You might have a BOM in your file; I get *a* syntax error in that case, but it complains about an unexpected token `(` rather than `do`.

Comment: BTW, leaving out the whitespace between `for` and `((` is... very unusual.

Comment: Anyhow, "using bash 4.1" means what? If you're just saying that's what you use interactively, but your script starts with `#!/bin/sh`, then it's a non sequitur. Ideally, you should be able to provide a script that causes the same error when it's run on an online interpreter like https://ideone.com/, so we can see the problem for ourselves.

Comment: In `help for`, note the whitespace in `for (( exp1; exp2; exp3 )); do COMMANDS; done` -- that's the expected/canonical syntax.

Comment: I used that syntax and got the same result so I do not think that that is the problem. Also, I do not use #/bin/sh in my script. The code that I posted above is the entire script which is then turned into an executable and submits jobs with certain parameters and also calls another script which actually runs the program.

Comment: Works fine on `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` if I add the first line `#!/bin/bash`